# MS ACCESS VBA coded Submit button to enter data for each day of the week

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba

I am currently trying to create a form to enter in an allocated number of hours for a day.

Each entry has 5 aspects:

- Date
- Resource
- Project
- Position
- Hours

The tricky part about the form is that I want to be able to enter records for all 5 days of any given week at the same time.

The form is set up with 4 ComboBox on top:

- Resource
- Project
- Position
- Week

And across the bottom are 5 TextBox each labeled with their respective day of the week.

I am very new to VBA, but from what I've gathered through research is that the best way to accomplish this is through VBA code behind a Submit button.

The code would need to submit 5 total records. One record for each week day. The Resource, project and position fields would come straight from the comboboxes and be the same for all 5 records. The hours field would come from 1 of the 5 textboxes corresponding to each day of the week. And the date field would be filled using the week combobox, but it would have to add on days depending on which record it is submitting(tuesday, +1, wednesday, +2,...).

So I know what I want to do, but I've been researching VBA and trying to learn how to accomplish this and it is confusing the hell out of me.

I would really appreciate any help or advice that anyone could offer in terms of how I would go about setting up the code to submit these records.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add a picture of your user interface because I do not understand. Does it even matter for your question? Also since you already know what to do you should write down your algorithm in pseudo code. Your description is too hard to follow. What is "a formula"? What table are you talking about?

Comment: The user interface is simply the 4 listed comboboxes across the top, and 5 text box, one for each week day, across the bottom with a submit button underneath that. The fields in the table are: date, resource, project, position, and hours. I'm not familiar with pseudo code but I will try to edit the description of it in my original post to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out so I'll post my code in case anyone cares. The code checks that all the controls are filled then loops through the records and inserts them into the table.

```
Private Sub Allocation_Submit_Click()
Dim sSQL As String
Dim k As Integer


'check for all values entered/selected
If Len(Nz(Me.cboMonDate, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing Week. Please make a selection."
    Me.cboMonDate.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Nz(Me.cboResource, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing Resource. Please make a selection."
    Me.cboResource.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Nz(Me.cboProject, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing Project. Please make a selection."
    Me.cboProject.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Nz(Me.cboPosition, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing Position. Please make a selection."
    Me.cboPosition.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

For k = 2 To 6
    If Len(Nz(Me("tbhour" & k), "")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Missing hours. Please enter hours for " & WeekdayName(k) & "."
        Me("tbhour" & k).SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

'build insert SQL string
For k = 2 To 6
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO Allocations (TheDate, Resource_ID, Project_ID, Position_ID, Hours)"
    sSQL = sSQL & " VALUES (#" & Me.cboMonDate + k - 2 & "#, " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", "
    sSQL = sSQL & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me("tbHour" & k) & ");"
    '        Debug.Print sSQL
    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
Next

Me.Requery

MsgBox "Done"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You want an SQL-Insert-statement:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_click()
  Dim qry as String
  Dim db as dao.database
  Set db = currentdb

  'First date
  qry = _
    "INSERT INTO YourTable
    "(" & Me.TxtDate1 & ", " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", " & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me.cboWeek & ");"
  db.execute qry

  'Second Date
  qry = _
    "INSERT INTO YourTable
    "(" & Me.TxtDate2 & ", " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", " & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me.cboWeek & ");"
  db.execute qry

  'Third Date
  qry = _
    "INSERT INTO YourTable
    "(" & Me.TxtDate3 & ", " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", " & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me.cboWeek & ");"
  db.execute qry

  'Fourth Date
  qry = _
    "INSERT INTO YourTable
    "(" & Me.TxtDate4 & ", " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", " & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me.cboWeek & ");"
  db.execute qry

  'Fifth Date
  qry = _
    "INSERT INTO YourTable
    "(" & Me.TxtDate5 & ", " & Me.cboResource & ", " & Me.cboProject & ", " & Me.cboPosition & ", " & Me.cboWeek & ");"
  db.execute qry

  set db = nothing

End Sub
```

More information on insert statements: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

This code does not work for alterations of existing records! For this you would need update statements: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Just from reading this code it looks like it accomplishes almost everything I wanted to but does it adjust the date according to each day of the week? To me it appears that the date would be the same for all 5 entries.